# PHP email attachment 0 byte file size when received

Tags: php, email, attachment, email-attachments

i have an email attachment script that does work and sends me a file with the correct name...however the file is 0 bytes.

here is the php:

```
          $namer = $_FILES["cv_upload"]["name"];
          $file ="/home2/deserul7/public_html/nkaccounting/"."temp_cv/"."".$namer."";
          $contenttype = $_FILES["cv_upload"]['type'];
          $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
          $file_size = filesize($file);
          $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
          fclose($handle);

          $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
          $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
          $name = basename($file);

          $eol = PHP_EOL;

          // Basic headers
          $header = "From: NK Accounting <sal@desertsunstudio.com>".$eol;
          $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";

          // Put everything else in $message
          $message = "--".$uid.$eol;
          $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".$eol;
          $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
          $message .= $msg2."<br><br><br>".$eol;
          $message .= "--".$uid.$eol;
          $message .= "Content-Type: ".$contenttype."; name=\"".$name."\"".$eol;
          $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
          $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"".$eol;
          $message .= $content.$eol;
          $message .= "--".$uid."--";

          if (@mail($ouremail, $subject2, $message, $header)){
            echo "sent";
          }
```

when i send it to my gmail it works fine but when i try to get it thru my mail app in my desktop it comes in at 0 bytes...please help

Comment: php's mail() is rather under featured, your a lot better off using the likes of phpmailer

Comment: Are you sure `$content` has anything in it? What does `echo strlen($content);` show?

Comment: @Barmar it echos out 12514; im unsure what this means

Comment: @tim this is for my portfolio/learning...ive struggled alot just to get the file to actually move from the tmp folder, id rather not use a library at this moment

Comment: well no one actually uses mail for much, so your not going to learn anything you would actual want to use a a real world situation

Comment: @tim It's not like he needs `mail` to do much, it just has to send the message that he gives it.

Comment: @sallycakes What are you unsure about? `strlen()` returns the length of a string, so that means `$content` has 12514 characters in it, so it's not really empty.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw source of the email when you receive it, to see if the attachment is in there?

Comment: I think you need two `$eol` between the `Content-Disposition` line and `$content`.

Comment: If it "works fine" in GMail but not a local "mail app" then I'd be looking somewhere other than your PHP code. Local virus software, ISP policies, etc. If this is something like a Word document, you're likely to have those sorts of issues.

Comment: @miken32 I try most of the time, occasionally I slip up. Sorry.

Comment: @miken32 I suspect that Gmail is "fixing" the error that I noticed regarding the missing blank line.

Comment: @miken32 Yeah, I noticed now -- I don't usually make a note of usernames.

Comment: @Barmar two $eol was the fix thank you!! also sorry im still kind of a noob in PHP

Answer (score 1):

There's supposed to be a blank line between the attachment header and the attachment contents. You only have one `$eol` there, so there's no blank line (you did it correctly for the part with `$msg2`). Change the `Content-Disposition` line to:

```
      $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"".$eol.$eol;
```

You can see things like this more easily if you use a here-string instead of concatenation.

```
$message = <<<EOF
--$uid
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

$msg2<br><br><br>
--$uid
Content-Type: $contenttype; name="$name"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$name"

$content
--$uid
EOF;
```

Comment: this is the correct answer! thank you very much Barmar